# How to give autogenerated SOAP webservice requests the same interface?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, cxf

I'm autogenerating `soap` webservice classes using `CXF` (wsdl2java).

The soap methods generated come from xml tags like:

```
<wsdl:message name="GetAvailabilityReq">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q1:GetAvailabilityReq"
            xmlns:q1="http://path.to./MyService" />
    </wsdl:message>
```

The generated webservice will have various methods like:

```
@WebService
public interface MyWebservice {
   @WebResult
   @WebMethod
   public AvailabilityRsp getAvailability(@WebParam AvailabilityReq req);

   @WebResult
   @WebMethod
   public BookingRsp getBooking(@WebParam BookingReq req);
}
```

How can I group all Requests under the same `interface`?

Eg `AvailabilityReq implements BaseReq` and `BookingReq implements BaseReq`? Or it could as well be `extends`.

Note: All request do NOT share a common interface by the provided `wsdl` file, but I'd like to have that generated.

I probably have to tell jaxb/cxf this on autogeneration, but how?

Comment: I am curious, as I was always did the other way around - java2wsdl

Comment: Maybe this plugin would help? http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/AutoInheritance+Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to provide the following information in the pom.xml:

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.2</version>
            </dependency>

        <extraargs>
            <extraarg>-xjc-XautoInheritance</extraarg>
            <extraarg>-xjc-XautoInheritance-xmlRootElementsImplement=package.to.MyCommonInterface</extraarg>
        </extraargs>
```